# What are different ways to use 'keyup' event within HTML?

Tags: html, angular, forms, keydown, input-parameters

I have seen following 4 ways to use `keyup` event within HTML?

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<input #inputstring (keyup)="doSomething(inputstring.value)"/>

<input #inputstring (keyup.enter)="doSomething(inputstring.value)"/>

<input type="text" #formReplay (keyup)="0" />
```

I want to understand what is difference between the above three statements.

I have seen in `angular` a `reference variable` is created starting with `#`.
I have seen bottom two approaches being used in angular.

```
<input #inputstring (keyup)="doSomething(inputstring.value)"/>

<input #inputstring (keyup.enter)="doSomething(inputstring.value)"/>
```

And, I have seen `onkeyup` used in plain `javascript`

I need some understanding on what are the various ways to use `keyup` in angular and in `pure JS`. 
Which one is a preferred way to use `keyup`?

Comment: When you say "I have seen" - it will be much of a help if you can refer to the places you saw those usages. Besides the `onkeyup` all rest seems like some kind of a templating/front-end framework or something like that.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: So as I already mentioned in my comment - it looks like some front-end framework, which in your case is angular. This is how they handle onKeyUp events. If you use angular - use their way of doing things.

Comment: can we use `onkeyup` in angular? also what are other ways to use `keyup` in other frameworks?

Comment: there might be some magic things that angular is doing for you when you use "keyup" so if you will use "onkeyup" instead - those magic things will not happen. regarding other frameworks - there are tens of frameworks.. you don't really expect someone to go and check them for you, right?

Comment: I recommend the reading of [Angular Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), notably the section about [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event). In short, one main difference is that, with `(keyup)="doSomething(...)"`, the event handler is a method of the component class, while with `onkeyup="myFunction()"`, the event handler is a function of the global scope. You should use event binding in Angular, as suggested by @Dekel.